# Restrict node.js filesystem access

Tags: linux, file-system, node.js, package-manager, npm

I have a Node.js app which has a lot of npm-dependencies, running on Linux (Centos) machine.

When Node starts, the script has access to the files outside its directory (as least by default), so malicious npm-package could traverse a directory tree and read config files, etc.

I would like to restrict FS access to the script directory only. Is this possible?

Comment: It's going to have the same permissions as the user that launches it... so create a user for the app to run as with the permissions you want.